# IntelliJ & Wildfly - hot deploy webapp

Tags: intellij-idea, wildfly, wildfly-8, intellij-14, hotswap

I am using IntelliJ (14.0.3) and Wildfly (8).

When I recompile my Java classes, hot swapping is easy and everything works just fine.  However, my HTML, JS and CSS files will not hot swap for me.  I am sure it is just a configuration issue and was hoping for some help.

My HTML data is in:

`<root>/<war_module>/src/main/webapp`

My run/debug is setup for:

> Before launch: Make, Build Artifacts
>
> 1. Make
> 2. Build 'mymodule:war' artifact

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the exact same problem, this is how it worked for me:

After configuring your JBoss server (Wildfly), setup an artifact of type **exploded**, in my case I selected **Web Application: Exploded**, and then in the Output directory add **.war** to the end of the name.

In case you need a **.ear**, simply select **JavaEE Application: exploded** instead, but anyways always remember to add manually the extension.

After setting this artifact to work with your Application Server, in the **edit configurations** of your Wildfly server select the option **Update resources** in the list of options in the section **On frame deactivation**.

So every time you modify and save static content, it will update these changes as soon as you focus something else outside the IDE, like the browser.

Comment: I was missing that last part:  "Update Resources on Frame Deactivation".  Thanks

Comment: I was missing the 'add the extension manually' part, which basically solved every problem I ever had with exploded war deployment inside IntelliJ, including with tomcat. I also needed to delete the warfile from `target` with IntelliJ 2018.3, as the ide build preceding the deploy does not create the directory if a file with the same name exists.